# What are most useful/used vim commands in C/C++ dev environment

Tags: c++, c, vim, vi

**Here is the list of mine**

Unlike me -- as I did it for illustrative purposes -- don't paste too many.

*And most importantly, provide an explanation*

Commands shouldn't be generic but relevant to C++/C environment.   ctags & scope are welcome too

```
gi .....................init insert mode in last insertion position

'0 .....................open last edited file

gf .....................open file under cursor in same window 

Ctrl-w q ...............close current window

:setlocal autoread .....Auto reloads the current buffer..especially useful while viewing log files

for i in range(1,255) | .put='10.0.0.'.i | endfor....   insert range ip's

g; and g, .......................to move (forward, backward) through the changelist

fx Move the cursor forward to the next occurrence of the character x on the current line (obviously, x can be any character you like). This is an extremely useful command. You can type ; to repeat the last f command you gave. 

tx Same as above, but moves the cursor to right before the character, not all the way to it. (It's very useful, really.) 

Fx Move the cursor backward to the next occurrence of the character x on the current line. 
w Move the cursor forward by a word. 
b Move the cursor backward by a word. 
0 Move the cursor to the beginning of the current line. 
^ Move the cursor to the first character on the current line. 
$ Move the cursor to the end of the line 


Visual search ....... you can simply yank the selected text with y and go to search mode 
/, then you can paste the last yanked text with Ctrl+R 0

ci" - cuts the text in current quotes
ciw - cuts the current word. This works just like the previous one except that ( is replaced with w.
C - cut the rest of the line and switch to Insert mode.
zz -- it scrolls the screen to make this line appear in the middle
C - cut the rest of the line and switch to Insert mode.
de - delete from cursor to the end of the word (you can also do dE to delete until the next space)
df[space] -- delete up until and including the next space
bye -- copies current word 
b and e move the cursor word-by-word
capital D (take a deep breath) Deletes the rest of the line to the right 
cd %:h change to current directory
:r! <command> pastes the output of an external command into the buffer.
:%s/foo/bar(&)/g will look for foo, and surround the matched pattern with bar().
:s/.*/PREFIX & SUFFIX/ you want to add a prefix and a suffix simultaneously, you can do something like this:

gd....... keystroke stands for Goto Declaration
gD....... This takes you to the global declaration of the variable under the cursor
------------------
:make error
[make_error]
On pressing RETURN, the cursor moves to line number 6
Now, the command :cn will move the cursor to the line number 4. 
To move back to the previous error, one can use the command :cN and the cursor will move back to the line 6. 
After correcting the error on line 5 and adding "return 1;", one can run :make again and the output will be 


---------
:%!grep sdf | sort -n -k3

1)select the whole content using '%' 
2) pipe it to an external command using '!' 
3) grep onyl the lines containing 'sdf' 
4) sort these lines numerically (-n) on the third field (-k3)


d$ will delete from current position to end of line 
d^ will delete from current backward to first non-white-space character 
d0 will delete from current backward to beginning of line 
dw deletes current to end of current word (including trailing space) 
db deletes current to beginning of current word 

:%s/pattern//gn........... For counting the number of times some pattern occurs, use:

CTRL-O   Go to [count] Older cursor position in jump list  
CTRL-I   Go to [count] newer cursor position in jump list


zz - line that has a cursor is in the middle of the screen
zt - line that has a cursor is in the top of the screen
zb - line that has a cursor is in the buttom of the screen

set printoptions=number:y  ...set numbers in a hardcopy 
:hardcopy.... to print the file :w

shift d ...... Deleting from current position to end of line
vim -o ....... allows you to open two windows, split vertically horizontally
vim -O ....... allows you to open two windows, split vertically
CTRL+W CTRL-Q ......to close the current windows
qall.........How do I quit all windows

0 ...First position on line
Ctrl g ...where am I
:set wrapmargin=70
printexpr=system('lpr' . (&printdevice == '' ? '' : ' -P' . &printdevice) . ' ' . v:fname_in) . delete(v:fname_in) + v:shell_error

Tab block of code ....select your block of code (with [V]isual line mode normally), then press > or <.
If you want to tab more than once, 2> or 3> to repeat it.
```

---

**News:**

```
 Guys, let's REOPEN THIS QUESTION, and go WIKI-CRAZY!
```

Comment: You could always look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69871/vim-vi-survival-guide question that asks "What are the essential vim commands?"

Comment: well those are general, I am particularly interested in those who use vim for c++ development environment.

Comment: So are all of your examples.  There aren't any C++ only constructs (that I am aware of) in vi/vim.

Comment: Not only c++, but, at the very least, pertinent. @amischiefr -- what is it that you're trying to achieve right now? Do you genuinely believe this the duplicate question? Are you just being anally stubborn, and picky about my wording?  Sorry -- English is not my first language. And in this thread I want to share C++ programmers' vim usage.

Comment: If this were wiki (which it doesn't need to be) I would answer :wq B-) snarkiness belongs only in wiki entries B-)

Comment: made it wiki -- let's re-open it

Answer (score 4):

One set of commands I find useful is [[, ]], [], ][. They navigate through curly braces on the first column, so they effectively allow you to walk through functions if you use proper indentation.

Answer (score 4):

The ones I overuse are the following :

- [`:AV`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31) to vertically split the current window and open the header/source file associated to the respective source/header file (if not yet opened, otherwise we jump to its window instead)
- [`:GSp` and `:GVSp`](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/searchInRuntime) to split the current window and open the requested file (which is somewhere in &path), or jump to the file if it is already opened
- [`<m-x>`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=23) to toggle comment on the current line
- [:Make](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/#svn/BTW/trunk%3Fstate%3Dclosed) to compile the current project in the background -- NB: a flag needs to be set in order to do so
- [`<c-x>be`](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp) to add `.begin(), /container_name/.end()` in `whatever(container_name<curoser_here>)`
- [`#i`](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp) which will expand into `#include`
- [`:DOX`](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp) which will add a doxygen comment to the current function prototype -- parameters const-/ref-ness, throw spec, return type are taken into account
- [`:GOTOIMPL`](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp) which will create a default body from the current function declaration (or jump to the already existing body when possible)
- [`<c-w><m-down>`](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/#svn/tags/trunk) : another way to navigate the tags base
- [`for/if/...`](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp) : expand into the relevant code snippet in insert mode (outside of string/comment context)
- [`,for/,if/.. and ,,for/,,if/...`](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp) to surround the current selection with the relevant code snippet, the selection will go into the control-statement body (one ,), or its condition (two ,)
- [`tpl`](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp) expands into `template <<cursor>><+placeholder+>`
- all the text-object motions with =, d, c, ... + [`di,/vi,/...`](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp) that acts on the current parameter
- [`<c-x>v`, `<c-x>t`](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhRefactor) to extract the selected variable/type (refactoring)
- [All the bracket opening characters + `<m-del>`](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhCpp) to maintain balanced brackets

There are many other commands I use when I develop in C++, but less often -- just explore the links I've given.

Answer (score 3):

Those may be usefull for programming

**=** - to intend text. To indent all file g CTRL+V G =

**CTRL-P/CTRL-O** - to complete text

**}y** - to paste block and indent it correctly in a new place. For example code block in clipboard is 2 level indentation and should be pasted in code, where it will be in 3 level indentation.

**CTRL-X+f** to complete file name

**>>/<<** - increase/decrease indentation

**%** - go the the corresponding open/close bracket

[minibufexpl](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159) is good plugin to work at once on several files

Answer (score 3):

`>aB` to indent a block. Not *frequently* used, but a gem nonetheless.

Comment: do u need to visually select the block first?

Comment: Nope, just have the cursor inside the block you want to indent. :)

Comment: @Andrei - ":help text-objects" will give you a better idea of all the commands with a similar structure. In this case "B" could also be "{" or "}" with the same meaning (I find this easier to remember). You can apply any operator (such as d for delete, or v for selection) as well as a count before this to apply to the block.

Answer (score 2):

Using different views is usefull for side by side code comparison.
Note each view created by a split can hold a separate file.

To split the view horizontally

```
:split
```

To split the view vertically

```
:vsplit
```

To move between split views

```
^W<arrow>      (Thats control W) (Arrow Key)
```

Once you have set up the tags file:

```
^]             (Move over identifier you want to find: Hit Control ])
:tn            Next Tag
:tp            Previous Tag
:pop           Pop back to the place you where when you hit ^]
```

Comment: +1 Because my vim sessions are split hells -- even if I don't directly use :sp and :vsp to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [SnippetsEmu](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1318). A great plugin that will save you a lot of regularly typed words in C.

*Note*: You're asking about commands and not plugins, but just wanted to mention this one anyway.

Comment: IMO, plugins are relevant: vim just by itself is quite poor to develop in C++ or even in C.

Answer (score 1):

The best I've ever used is when I used a combination of combining [running make](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/gcc-from-within-vim-481820/) and [Quickfix](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/quickfix.html). I pressed F6 to compile, and then F7 to move backwards through the errors and F8 to move forwards by using the line numbers in the gcc warning / error output. Quicker than alt-tab, press up.